# moment.tz using UTC

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am having a hard time trying to get my head around moment.tz, basically I am coverting a time to Europe/Zurich time

```
       moment
          .tz(moment(time), 'Europe/Zurich')
          .format()
```

instead of this I would like to convert it on the UTC time instead of EUROPE/ZURICH, I tried using

```
moment
          .utc(time)
          .format()
```

without success, is there a way to do it the same way I am doing it on the first examle?,i.e:

```
       moment
          .tz(moment(time), 'UTC')
          .format()
```

or would it be flying to high?

thanks for your time